# unable to load .csv file contents correctly into python data frame

Tags: python, csv

For an in class assignment, I am attempting to load a csv file into a dataframe in python using Jupyter notebook.

The below is my attempt. I have defined columns as such:

```
gnacs_y = "id|postedTime|body|None1|['twitter_entiteis:urls:url']|None2|['actor:languages_list-items']|gnip:language:value|twitter_lang|[u'geo:coordinates_list-items']|geo:type|None3|None4|None5|None6|actor:utcOffset|None7|None8|None9|None10|None11|None12|None13|None14|None15|actor:displayName|actor:preferredUsername|actor:id|gnip:klout_score|actor:followersCount|actor:friendsCount|actor:listedCount|actor:statusesCount|Tweet|None16|None17|None18"
colnames = gnacs_y.split('|')
```

Then I have the following:

```
df_3 = pd.read_csv('../data/twitter_sample.csv', sep='|', names=colnames)

df_3.tail(10)
```

However when the data gets loaded i see only the ID column with what seems like HTML code text and all the other columns are NaN where as there is data in the .CSV file. I have attached screen shots of what i see in the jupyter notebook and the content of the CSV file. I am not sure if I messed up the initial declaration of the column names under gancs_y.

Link to the CSV file for the assignment:
https://github.com/terratenney/yorkBigData/blob/master/assignments/data/twitter_sample.csv

Any help would be great appreciated
[image: result of load]
[image: csv file content]

Answer (score 0):

Your file is not a `csv` file, it's a `html` file that has tables in it. If your assignment says you should have a `csv` file have you checked you downloaded the right file?

EDIT: It looks like you messed up saving your file - if you click the RAW button on Github and download that, it will give you the correct `csv` file without the `html`

Comment: Hi Louise, thanks for your reply. I have checked the file 3 times and it is with the extension .CSV; i will update the initial question with the file so that you can have a look perhaps. In the mean time i will copy paste the contents into a notepad and try it as a .HTML file as well. Thanks for your input

Comment: The original file would be useful, or just a plain text sample of the file (not in excel). I can't really tell what the `html` is doing in there and whether this is actually a file that could be salvaged so that it can be read by `read_csv`.

Comment: Hi Louise, I have added a link to the original file in the question. Please let me know if you are able to open it. Thanks again

Comment: Just because the extension is `.csv` doesn't mean it actually contains CSV data. Have you opened up your local copy and looked at it?
The link you posted is, in fact, an HTML file with a `.csv` extension. If you were to right click -> save as the link you've given us, that's exactly what you'd get. You need to click the "Raw" link on that page to get just the CSV data.

Comment: Thanks Mark, i clicked on the RAW link and i saw the raw data; i will copy and paste that data into a text file, save it as a csv, and perhaps that will solve this problem. Will report back on my attempt.

Comment: Ok i have got it work, thanks Mark and Louise for the help